# I'm getting an intermittent unhandled client-side "Internal error" with Blazor WebAssembly 11 seconds after page load

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a web app which consists of mostly a multi-step wizard style web form. The app uses the render mode `RenderMode.InteractiveAuto`, which as I understand it performs the initial load in server mode then downloads the WebAssembly in the background, so when it finally loads that, all interactivity is super fast.

This appears to work fine in that users can step through the wizard, and I'm succesfully getting form submissions.

I'm now starting to ramp up traffic to the site, and using Browsee.io to track funnel conversion. This app has highlighted some intermittent client-side JavaScript errors that I don't get when I run the app in `InteractiveServer` mode.

The error itself doesn't have much information, it just says `TypeError - https://mywebsite.com "Internal error" File https://mywebsite.com, in _promiseRejectionHandler`

When this error occurs, it seems to always happen at around the 11 second mark from the site being ready, which leads me to believe something (for example the WASM) has timed out from loading (after maybe 10 seconds).

The error itself doesn't appear to block the interactivity, so the form can still be submitted, however I'd ideally like to work out what's happening and if something I can / need to handle.

[image]